# scipy.optimize linprog doesnt return minimal solution I'd expect it to

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I read that linprog from scipy returns minimal solutions and one could get the optimal by multiply the objective function by -1.

I read it here: https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/
And I've tested the example they provided to see if i could get the minimal solution too -- I could.

Regarding the problem im trying to solve
I would expect the solutions to be:

```
opt_sol1.x = [0.61538462 0.38461538]
opt_sol2.x = [0.0, 1.0]
```

but i get the same result [0.61538462 0.38461538] in both cases why? -- my guess is it relates to the values in my objective function to be close to one another but just a guess
And is there a way i can get the second solution im looking for?

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

obj_fct1 = [0.5, 0.5]
obj_fct2 = [-0.5, -0.5]
lhs_ineq = [[1.5, 0.2]]
rhs_ineq = [1]
lhs_eq = [[1,1]]
rhs_eq = [1]
bnds = [(0, 1),
          (0, 1)]

opt_sol1 = linprog(c=obj_fct1,
                  A_ub=lhs_ineq,
                  b_ub=rhs_ineq,
                  A_eq=lhs_eq,
                  b_eq=rhs_eq,
                  bounds=bnds)
print(opt_sol1.x)
print("------------------------------------------")
opt_sol2 = linprog(c=obj_fct2,
                  A_ub=lhs_ineq,
                  b_ub=rhs_ineq,
                  A_eq=lhs_eq,
                  b_eq=rhs_eq,
                  bounds=bnds)
print(opt_sol2.x)


>>> [0.61538462 0.38461538]
>>> ------------------------------------------
>>> [0.61538462 0.38461538]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "issue" here is that there are an infinite number of minima and maxima for this problem, with the objective function equal to the same value for all optimal solutions (ignoring the sign flip for maximization). This can be seen by examining your equality constraint relative to your objective function and noting that they are linear combinations of each other. In the case of linear programs, the optimal solution lies on the boundary, either a line or vertex. If it is at a vertex and not a line, then there is a unique solution, but if it lies on a line, then there are infinite solutions. Because your objective function and equality constraint are linear combinations of each other, the consequence is that there are an infinite number of solutions and the minima and maxima are the same.

In your case, your objective is `f(x1, x2) = 0.5*x1 + 0.5*x2` or, equivalently, `f(x1, x2) = 0.5*(x1 + x2)`. Your equality constraint says that `x1 + x2 = 1`, so we see that `f(x1, x2) = 0.5` is the result. (If we were maximizing, we would change the sign of the objective function as you did and get that `f(x1,x2) = -0.5` for all feasible solutions.)

Considering there are an infinite number of solutions for both the maximization and minimization problems, why does the solver always return `[0.61538462 0.38461538]`? The default solver uses a form of the SIMPLEX algorithm, which always returns a vertex value (even when there is a line of solutions, a vertex value is still a solution, and this narrows down the number of possible solutions that need to be checked). In this case, there is a vertex when `x1 + x2 = 1` and `1.5*x1 + 0.2*x2 = 1` intersect, which is at `x1 = 8/13` and `x2 = 5/13`.